# State machine and unsigned signal

Tags: vhdl

I have a few problems with a fairly simple state machine I made. No matter what I do, the signal startS1, startS2, enS and mS always stays unsigned in simulation even when I hit the reset button and I can't figure out why. There's a component in the mix, but I did test the component and it works perfectly. I hope you can help me!

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity machine_etat is
generic (N_bit : integer := 8);
Port ( LOAD : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N_bit-1 downto 0);
       RESET : in STD_LOGIC;
       START : in STD_LOGIC;
       CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
       OUTPUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N_bit-1 downto 0));
end machine_etat;

architecture Behavioral of machine_etat is

TYPE machine is (IddleT, DepartT, LoadT, ShiftT, EndT);
SIGNAL Etat1, Etat2 : machine:= IddleT;

SIGNAL mS: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
SIGNAL enS : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL outputS : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N_bit-1 downto 0);

component Reg_decal is
generic (N_bit : integer := N_bit);
Port ( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
RESET : in STD_LOGIC;
EN : in STD_LOGIC;
M : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
LOAD : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N_bit-1 downto 0);
OUTPUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N_bit-1 downto 0));
end component;

SIGNAL startS1, startS2 : STD_LOGIC;

begin

OUTPUT <= outputS;


Reg_dec: Reg_decal 
    generic map (N_bit => N_bit)
    port map (CLK => CLK,
              RESET => RESET,
              EN => enS,
              M => mS,
              LOAD => LOAD,
              OUTPUT => outputS);

Machine1: process (CLK)
begin
    if RESET = '1' then
        enS <= '0';
        mS <= "00";
        startS1 <= '0';
        startS2 <= '0';
        Etat1 <= IddleT;
    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
        CASE Etat1 is
            WHEN IddleT =>
                if startS1 = '1' OR START = '1' then
                    Etat1 <= DepartT;
                 else
                    Etat1 <= IddleT;
                 end if;

            WHEN DepartT =>
                Etat1 <= LoadT;
                startS1 <= '0';
            WHEN LoadT =>
                mS <= "11";
                enS <= '1';
                Etat1 <= ShiftT;

            WHEN ShiftT =>
                mS <= "00";
                Etat1 <= EndT;

            WHEN EndT =>
                enS <= '0';
                startS2 <= '1';
                Etat1 <= IddleT;

            WHEN Others =>
                Etat1 <= IddleT;
        end CASE; 
   end if;
end process;

Machine2: process (CLK)

begin
if RESET = '1' then
    Etat2 <= IddleT;
elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
            CASE Etat2 is
                WHEN IddleT =>
                    if startS2 = '1' then
                        Etat2 <= DepartT;
                    else
                        Etat2 <= IddleT;
                    end if;

                WHEN DepartT =>
                    startS2 <= '0';
                    Etat2 <= LoadT;

                WHEN LoadT =>
                    enS <= '1';
                    Etat2 <= ShiftT;

                WHEN ShiftT =>
                    mS <= "01";
                    Etat2 <= EndT;

                WHEN EndT =>
                    Etat2 <= IddleT;
                    startS1 <= '1';
                WHEN Others =>
            end CASE;
        end if;
    end process;


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: 'X' not unsigned. IEEE Std 1076-2008  
16.8.2.2 The STD_LOGIC_1164 values "The values 'U', 'X', 'W', and '–' are metalogical values; they define the behavior of the model itself rather than the behavior of the hardware being synthesized. The value 'U' represents the value of an object before it is explicitly assigned a value during simulation; the values 'X' and 'W' represent forcing and weak values, respectively, for which the model is not able to distinguish between logic levels." Your driving the signals from both processes.

Comment: The answer simply stating add reset  demonstrates the need for a [mcve] capable of replicating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `RESET` to your process sensitivity list.

Comment: Fair point, but even if I keep RESET to '1' for longer than a clock cycle or if I add RESET to my sensitivity list, I still get unsigned value for startS1, startS2, mS and enS...

Comment: Sorry, I only had a minute to glance at it. Now I notice you're driving the aforementioned signals from both your processes which causes contention. You can only drive signals from one place, whether that be in the main architecture or from within a single process.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was my problem indeed! Have a good day :)